# How to quickly find to the largest files recursively in bash from a large amount of files

Tags: bash, shell

I have lots of logs and files on a server I ssh to. Like all logs, they grow. I like to monitor this but currently I only know that the disk is getting full and perform commands like

```
sudo du -sh * #dirs in this dir filesizes
ls -l --sort=size | head -10 #10 biggest files in dir
```

to spot the files causing the problem and address it. It's slow and manual or I have commands like

```
find . -type f -exec du -b {} + | sort -nr | head -n 1
```

that go through every file, of which there are lots, and therefore takes too long.  Normally the problem is that only a couple of files have got significantly larger than anything else in the file system.

The solution doesn't have to be a one liner and could even be a shell script etc. Anything that gets the job done quickly would be helpful like perhaps finding all files over a size threshold would be a reasonable option too.

Most important requirement: It works quickly.

Comment: *perhaps finding all files over a size threshold would be a reasonable option too.* very good idea, have you tried that?

Comment: *"of which there are lots"* how many?

Comment: Try to use `logrotate`

Comment: @perpetuallynotfini : The time it takes is that every script needs at least look at each file to find out its size. Even `du -s` needs to do this. If the  only files you are interested in, are logfiles, you can for instance make naming conventions for them.We use for instance the extension `.log` in our project. Hence, `find` would only have to scan the directories and pick the files with this extension for closer investigation.

Comment: @perpetuallynotfini : Another approach - if this is feasible in your application - is to put the burden into the program which actually **generates** those files. Maybe it can update some kind of central data repository with information of what files it has generated, and also provide a rough estimate of the number of log entries written. Then you only have to scan this "database" to look for interesting files.

Comment: Agree with comments above,  `du -s` is going to be the basis of your fastest solution.. If you can point all your log files to at least a base dir, the `du -sm * | sort -nr` would be good. Note I'm NOT using `-h` option to `du`, as that doesn't sort well. I don't have a way to test, but I would expect `du -sm ../dir1/* ./other/path/* /third/path .... | sort -rn` to work, but not sure if you'd be able to tell which directory was biggest. If that is the case, if gets a bit more complicate, but doable. Good luck!

Comment: i would stay with plain `du -axd1 *.log | sort -nr | head -n10` it's not slow when you limit search to current dir. recursive way *find -exec stat sort head* seems fastest you can get

Answer (score 2):

`du` is your friend.

```
$: du $baseDir | sort -rn | head -$worstOffenders
```

You might need a `sudo` on that `du`.

## Addendum

Thanks for calling this out Franck. Apparently I didn't read the OP very carefully. My answer was kind of stupid, and the one downvote is well deserved. Let me try and fix that.

A better solution would be to take the `-exec` out.

`find`'s `-printf` option has a ton of available data, including file size.

Realizing it's years old, this can still be helpful for someone.
Try something like this:

```
find . -type f -size +2G -printf '%s\t%h/%f\n' | sort -nr | head -n 1
```

That outputs the file size in bytes, then a tab, then the file's path (`%h`) and name (`%f`).

Adding the `-size +2G` (use the biggest value you can to eliminate the maximum number of hits) should considerably speed up the `du` version. It helps a little on the `-printf` version too, but the bigger that limit, the more it will close the gap between the two approaches, as the less often it will run the `-exec`.

If it helps, some comparative time tests using increasing values of `-maxdepth`.

```
$: for d in 2 3 4 5; do time find . -maxdepth $d -type f -size +2G -printf '%s\t%h/%f\n' | sort -nr | head -n 1; time find . -maxdepth $d -type f -size +2G -exec du -b {} + | sort -nr | head -n 1; done
11274289152     ./pagefile.sys

real    0m0.049s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.061s
11274289152     ./pagefile.sys

real    0m0.057s
user    0m0.030s
sys     0m0.077s
11274289152     ./pagefile.sys

real    0m1.564s
user    0m0.218s
sys     0m1.357s
11274289152     ./pagefile.sys

real    0m1.528s
user    0m0.311s
sys     0m1.233s
11274289152     ./pagefile.sys

real    0m11.910s
user    0m1.780s
sys     0m10.061s
11274289152     ./pagefile.sys

real    0m12.013s
user    0m1.951s
sys     0m9.951s
11274289152     ./pagefile.sys

real    8m25.509s
user    0m4.999s
sys     0m40.546s
11274289152     ./pagefile.sys

real    14m30.288s
user    0m5.640s
sys     0m51.358s
```

Comment: If the folder contains subfolders, this command also lists subfolders (instead of actual files, assuming that the subfolder total size is larger than the largest file).